# Modules to run through folders and sub folders

Tags: module, directory-structure

The program looks in the currrent directory for files starting with "Oddball_" & ending with ".csv" and then runs those files through modules numbered 1 through 4 based on the filename.

This works correctly for the files in the root directory, however when navigating further in folders and sub folders it produces errors.

## calculate_results.py

```
import sort_run1
import sort_run2
import sort_run3
import sort_run4

# Import the os module, for the os.walk function
import os

# Set the directory you want to start from
rootDir = '.'
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for filename in fileList:
        if filename.startswith('Oddball_') and filename.endswith('.csv'):
            if dirName not in fileList:
                print('directory location: ' + dirName)
                if filename.startswith('Oddball_1'):
                    sort_run1.sort1(filename)
                elif filename.startswith('Oddball_2'):
                    sort_run2.sort2(filename)
                elif filename.startswith('Oddball_3'):
                    sort_run3.sort3(filename)
                elif filename.startswith('Oddball_4'):
                    sort_run4.sort4(filename)
                else:
                    continue
        else:
            continue
```

## sort_run1.py:  sort_run2.py / sort_run3.py / sort_run4.py are all similar

```
import pandas as pd
import pathlib

def sort1(pid):
    print(pid)
    # Name of file to read
    filename = pid
        
    # data frame to create from file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    
##
##I've removed all the stuff that happens here to minimize code
##
```

The intended output is to run through all files in the folders.

Answer (score 0):

In my sort_run1.py file, I had

`df = pd.read_csv(filename)`

but needed the following

`df = pd.read_csv(f'.//{dir_name}//{filename}')`